# /bin/proxychains: line 9: exec: [url] : not found

Tags: lamp

I'm setting up `/etc/proxychains.conf`. When I use `proxyresolv` it's okay:

```
proxyresolv myipaddress.com
|R-chain|-<>-*********:443-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
64.99.64.37
```

But `proxychains` doesn't work:

```
proxychains myipaddress.com
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
/bin/proxychains: line 9: exec: myipaddress.com: not found
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

That's not what the `proxychains` command does. It expects you to give it a command in which it will provide a chained proxy. You specify the proxy in your configuration.

See `man proxychains` for more detail.

Comment: my question is "when i use proxyresolv its ok but i use proxychains getting error" , why>?

Comment: @HasanAmiri Because they're different commands. That's like asking why `ls` and `rm` don't do the same thing.